# What happens to the binaries generated after compilation

Tags: c, process, operating-system, microcontroller

I create a hex file for my microcontroller and I burn it on the microcontroller.
When I create a console C program and try to run it on my PC do my PC's Operating system do the similar with the binary file generated after compilation? And in this case target is my PC's microprocessor.

Comment: Similar? Well, somewhat. Too broad.

Comment: Yes.............

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not similar. When you compile something targeting a µc, your compiler will typically emit *exactly* the machine code running on this controller.

Targeting a modern operating system, the compiler emits machine code as well, but puts it in a file with a lot of *meta information*, the format depends on the target OS (e.g. PE (= portable executable) for Windows, ELF for Linux and other *nix systems). These meta informations contain things like

- The exact entry point in the program (while a *naked* binary would just start execution at the first byte)
- Possibly relocation information (what must be changed in the code if it's executed from a different address)
- A symbol table needed to link libraries during runtime, so addresses of the library functions can be patched into the executable
- [...]

This executable file is then loaded by your operating system and interpreted before any execution can start.

Comment: That means I can edit the code in this way that I can edit the priority of interrupts and can play with the core peripheral.

Comment: sorry, what? :o

Comment: Do I have permission to alter the processor's usual work by altering binaries (or creating such binaries). For example DMA , PCI bus

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about :o on a µc, you *typically* have no OS in place, so you can do with the hardware whatever you want. I was under the impression you were asking how executable files for a PC OS work. Of course, the OS has **exclusive** control over the hardware!

Comment: Thanks I got it now. And yes I was asking about the executables for PC OS . Once again thank you

Comment: First bullet: "a naked binary would just start execution at the first byte" is not accurate.  The reset vector decides where to start, and that's not necessarily the first byte of the binary.

Comment: @tonypdmtr I know, but a) many platforms indeed coldstart at 0 and b) there are many possibilities, e.g. binaries containing the vector, I decided to sacrifice a bit of precision for simplicity here.